# Does completing official graduate admission application mean that I'm not allowed to apply for another university?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

I'm working to prepare my master's degree admission.

So the admission team provided me with a declaration form and I'm want to know what exactly the last two points mean:

> **Read the following and agree below:**
>
> • I will read and accept the responsibility of the Honor Code if I am
> approved for admission to ... University.
>
> • I certify that all information given on this application is
> complete, true, accurate and my own original work.
>
> • I ensure that the academic credentials provided are authentic and
> have not been altered.
>
> • I confirm that the I-20 Shipping Address provided in the application
> is an address where I personally receive mail.
>
> • I confirm that I have included information on all of my academic
> studies and will not pursue further study prior to joining this
> university. Failure to provide this information can result in
> dismissal from the university. By selecting yes, this will serve as a
> signed agreement:
>
> □ Yes □ No

My guess for the last two points is:

1. The I-20 shipping address would be my actual address in the city I work and live in.
2. The "not pursue further study" would mean, as I complete the admission application process and get the agreement from the university that they accepted me in the graduate study whether the admission is direct or connected with finishing an English course, that I will not get involved in pursuing any higher education.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This means that you receive mail at this address. In other words, this is your address, not your brother's address (or some such).
2. "Pursue further study" means pursue graduate study in the field you apply for. For example if you're applying for a MSc in Aeronautical engineering, then you are saying that you will not be enrolling in another Aeronautical engineering MSc program while this application is being processed. If you do, then you may be dismissed.

You are allowed to apply to many programs, however. Applying is not the same as pursuing further study.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can apply to as many universities as you like. What it means is that if you accept another offer and actually join that program, then your current application becomes void.

But it doesn't limit your ability to apply elsewhere.

I doubt that it would actually even apply to a single term-length course (say to fill a gap), but only to joining another degree program.

It would actually be improper for a university to try to limit your action prior to accepting you into a program.